# Inconsistent fading on flag panel

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When flagging, the off-topic panel does not fade in and out, while all others have some sort of fade effect before showing up the next screen.  Personally, I find the fading in and out rather obtrusive and gives the impression of longer times to be usable, even when I know that nothing is actually being loaded.  Could this be removed?

Comment: Well most of the transitions on the flagging panel do require a get request to be populated. Like the duplicate panel. And actually the off-topic does not require any other request, so I guess that's why there is no loading.

Comment: @HugoDozois: only duplicates require a get request.

Comment: nope...  "it should be closed for another reason…" requires a get request too.. to /posts/popup/close/suggest-originals .